# How can I fill a small hole in fiber cement siding?

Tags: siding

I've found a couple small holes in my home's fiber cement siding. What's the best way to fill them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you have some small cracks and holes in your siding, you can fill them in with patching material specifically designed for this purpose, available at your local hardware store. Keep in mind that the patching will be obvious, whether or not you paint over it, so this is the best solution if the cracks and holes are in out of the way places that aren’t readily noticeable. If you have really big holes and cracks, then the siding will probably have to be replaced altogether."

Source: http://www.doityourself.com/stry/how-to-repair-fiber-cement-siding#b

Comment: Since the article isn't very specific about what to use, I'll suggest Bondo. If the hole is really big, you'll need to get some kind of backer in there. If possible, screws set below the finish surface can help lock the filler in place. Note that there's a point in Bondo's curing cycle where it's like very stiff Jello and you can slice it away with a long knife. After that, it's hard to sand excess off.